# Memcached crashing under moderate load

Tags: memcached

When running memcached, after a few minutes of use it starts throwing the following errors and memcache stops responding.

mcm_server_connect_next_avail():2328

I have searched the Google, and it seems many people are having this issue, but the only solution I have found was 'restart the server'.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Is this running in a clustered setup?

Comment: Couple of questions to ask yourself: how many simultaneous connections to your memcached server are you attempting? Is it a ridiculous number? Next, do you need to lock memory down using the -k command line option when starting memcached?

Comment: We are running on just one machine now for testing purposes.

Comment: Which version of memcached?  Is the server crashing or the client?  Have you captured stats while this is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a limitation with using the cmemcache library. If we use python-libmemcache everything is fine.